# Restore Zimbra mailbox with zmmailbox connection refused

Tags: restore, zimbra, mailbox

i'm trying to import mailboxes with

```
zmmailbox -z -m "$user@$domain.com" postRestURL “//?fmt=tgz&resolve=reset” $SOURCE
```

but always i get:

```
zclient.IO_ERROR (Refused connection)
```

i have 3 days reading the zimbra forums and nothing i've tryed set `zimbraAttachmentsIndexingEnabled` to `FALSE` (for account and COS) and `zmcontrol restart` as zimbra user

There other way to restore a mailbox account without `zmmailbox` and without using `zmlmtpinject` i don't wanna extract all mailboxes some have 20GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is for the internal DNS the command is trying to connect to other host with append

```
#/etc/hosts
[ip] domain.com
```

this problem is solved